# Letters of the word "ZAMBEZIA"

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We will take 3 letters from the letters of "ZAMBEZIA". What is the probability of getting 2 vowels and 1 consonant from the taking? I kinda confused whether I should do it immediately like:
Z, A, M, B, E, Z, I, A;
has 4 vowels and 4 consonants, and a total of 8 letters, so the probability is
$$ P(A) = C(4, 2) . C(4, 1)/C(8, 3) $$
or:
letters in ZAMBEZIA is Z, A, M, B, E, I;
has 3 vowels and 3 consonants, and a total of 6 letters, so the probability is
$$P(A) = C(3, 2) . C(3, 1)/C(6, 3)$$
I don't know which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should take
$$S = \{ Z, A, M, B, E, Z, I, A \} $$

This is a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), also denoted as

$$S = \{ 2\cdot A, B, E, I, M, 2\cdot Z \} $$

with multiplicity of elements mentioned. It is different from the set

$$S' = \{ A, B, E, I, M, Z \} $$

where each element occurs only once.